# Div element pushed out of the page when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have my video and its caption at the center of my page and my logo in the upper left corner. This works fine until resizing, when the logo is pushed out of the page - it is as if there was an element in the middle that overrides my logo element. I have tried to troubleshoot which element does this: I of course suspect that it is the video container, and I have tried many ways to change its settings with no success so far (absolute with smaller width, float left etc.).

I'm total newbie with CSS and would appreciate any help! I'm also aware that using absolute positions is not a good practice - it was now just something to get things working to some extent.

My code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Broadcaster</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:wght@400;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yatra+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Vollkorn:wght@400;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=BioRhyme&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/2.0.1/tf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="video-container">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted width="400" height="400" id="webcam"></video>
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='archive.html';" value="Archive" />
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='about.html';" value="About"/>
<div class="logo">
  <div id="icon">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
    <div id="box3"></div>
    <div id="logotext"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/broadcast.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css (this covers content on several html pages):

```
html,

html {
  height: 100%;

}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  background-color: #FFE4E1;
  background: linear-gradient(#FFE4E1, thistle);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


header {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 10%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Messapia-Bold', serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-5%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);

}

.video-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.video-container video {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  min-height: 224px;
  max-height: 600px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  }

.video-container #caption {

  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Messapia-Bold', serif;
  font-size: small;
  }


input[type=button] {
  font-family: 'Messapia-Bold', serif;

  font-size: small;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right:3%;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-family: 'Messapia-Bold', serif;

  font-size: small;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:3%;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=back] {
  font-family: 'Messapia-Bold', serif;

  font-size: small;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19%;
  left:3%;
  text-align: center;
}


.text {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
}

.text p{
  text-align: center;
  padding:  0 26%;
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;

  font-size: x-large;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Messapia-Bold";
src: url("font/Messapia-Bold.woff2") format ("woff2"),
src: url("font/Messapia-Bold.woff") format ("woff");
}



.logo{
  min-width: 11%;
  min-height: 11%;
  margin:1em 0em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/


}

#icon{
  position: absolute; 
  min-width:100%; 
  min-height:100%; 
  margin:1em 0em;
  overflow: visible;
}

#icon > *{
   display: inline-block;  
   position: absolute;
   overflow: visible;
}
#icon div span{
    display:none;
}


#logotext{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-image:url(/logo/final_transparent.svg) ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  overflow: visible;
}

#box1{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-image:url(/logo/final_upperbox.svg) ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;

  animation-name: stretch1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  transform-origin: 97% 50%;
  overflow: visible;

}

#box2{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-image:url(/logo/final_midbox.svg) ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  overflow: visible;

}

#box3{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-image:url(/logo/final_lowestbox.svg) ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;

  animation-name: stretch3;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  transform-origin: 97% 50%;
  overflow: visible;
}


@keyframes stretch1 {
  0% {
     transform: scaleX(0);
   }
   100% {
     transform: scaleX(1);
   }
}

@keyframes stretch2 {
  0% {
     transform: scaleX(0);
   }
   100% {
     transform: scaleX(1);
   }
}

@keyframes stretch3 {
  0% {
     transform: scaleX(0);
   }
   100% {
     transform: scaleX(1);
   }
}



.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 6px;
}


.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding:  0 6px;
}

.column img {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are a few `min-width:100%;` Did you use `min-width` (minimal full width) for a reason?

Comment: Yep, I tried to test if that prevents the logo from getting squashed but did not work!

Comment: Better to change it in `max-width:100%;`  Some things to look for: The `left:...%` pushes an element to the right. Using horizontal margin may push an element out of view. The `display:inline-block` gives an extra space on the right side of the element.